# How to have markdown content in components in MDX files?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

I'm working on a project with MDX pages using React components. When I add text inside the component I would like to have HTML generated (like with content outside of components). But the generated page has only text inside the component and not HTML.

This is my code:

Component js:

```
<Container>
    {props.children}
</Container>
```

MDX page:

```
<Component>
     **Generated HTML**
</Component>
```

Generated page:

```
<div>
     **Generated HTML**
</div>
```

Expected behaviour:

```
<div>
     <p><strong>Generated HTML</strong></p>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [`@next/mdx`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx)?

Comment: Yes of course, the whole project uses it

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/filipowm/gatsby-gitbook-starter/issues/11), I just needed to add a new line between the tags like this:

```
<Component>

**Generated HTML**

</Component>
```

Thanks for the help!